# Only Allow Sever to Post to AWS S3 and Not Client Side App - Server Code & S3 Config

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm working on a project that allows users to upload images.

First the client sends the image to the server and then from there the server uploads it to the amazons S3 bucket.

I only want the server with valid credentails to have the access to upload to S3 and not the client.

My Server is uploading the clients images to S3.

However I am unable to enforce the S3 bucket to only allow uploads from the server with the correct credential.

If I remove the AWS S3 credentials from the server the server is still able to upload the images to S3 which is not the intended result.

```
'use strict'

const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') 
    require('dotenv').config();


// Set credentials and region
var s3 = new S3(    {
    region: process.env.S3_REGION,
    accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESSKEYID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRETACCESSKEY
});


function uploadImage(bufferImage) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let key = `${uuid()}.png`;
        let params = { Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET, Key: key, Body: bufferImage };

        console.log('uploadImage invoked');
        s3.putObject(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error', err);
                return reject("This error");
            }

            return resolve(`https://s3.${process.env.S3_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${process.env.S3_BUCKET}/${key}`);
        });
    });
}


function removeImage(imageUri) {
    console.log(imageUri);
    var params = {
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
        Key: imageUri.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
    };

    s3.deleteObject(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            return Promise.reject(err);
        Promise.resolve(data);
    });
}


module.exports = { uploadImage, removeImage };
```

Here is a copy of my S3 bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Any help on achieving the intended result would be much appreciated! - Only allowing the server to post images to S3 and not the client Also allowing the client to view the images but not post to S3 directly.